# What's the best practice if my Flink application needs to have a high parallel sink in EMR?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, apache-flink, amazon-emr

I have a question about how I can configure my flink application on EMR in order to have a high availability of Jobs.
I'm working with EMR and I must use a m5.xlarge or m5a.xlarge with 4vcores an 16GiB.

First of all I init flink session with this command:

```bash
flink-yarn-session -d -jm 2048 -tm 4096 -s 4 \
-D state.backend=rocksdb \
-D state.backend.incremental=true \
-D state.checkpoint-storage=filesystem \
-D state.checkpoints.dir=S3Path \
-D state.checkpoints.num-retained=10 \
-D execution.checkpointing.interval=10s \
-D execution.checkpointing.mode=EXACTLY_ONCE \
-D execution.checkpointing.externalized-checkpoint-retention=RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION \
-D execution.checkpointing.max-concurrent-checkpoints=1
```

Then I run a Python Flink job with

```bash
flink run --python /home/hadoop/flink.py --MyVariables
```

And everything is good, the problem is that, I need to have 8 Jobs in parallel and in order to have them I have to use an m5.2xlarge or m5a.2xlarge, 'case every job is using one vcore.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

My source application is a MSK Cluster
My sink application is with hudi, following the next structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Sink(
    col1 string,
    col2 string,
    ...
    col68 string,
    primary key(col1) not enforced
)
    WITH(
        'connector' = 'hudi',
        'path' = 'S3Path',
        'table.type' = 'MERGE_ON_READ',
        'read.streaming.enabled' = 'true',
        'read.streaming.check-interval' = '4',
        'hoodie.datasource.write.hive_style_partitioning'='true',
        'compaction.delta_commits' = '1',
        'compaction.delta_seconds' = '300'
    );
```

And the Query/Job is:

```sql
Insert into Sink
    select 
        cast(json_value(key, '$.col1') as string) as Col1, 
        cast(json_value(key, '$.col2') as string) as Col2,
        ...
        cast(json_value(key, '$.col68') as string) as Col68,  
    from 
        Kafka_Source
    where
        Condition_1
    union all
    select 
        cast(json_value(key, '$.col1') as string) as Col1, 
        cast(json_value(key, '$.col2') as string) as Col2,
        ...
        cast(json_value(key, '$.col68') as string) as Col68,  
    from 
        Kafka_Source
    where
        Condition_2
    select 
        cast(json_value(key, '$.col1') as string) as Col1, 
        cast(json_value(key, '$.col2') as string) as Col2,
        ...
        cast(json_value(key, '$.col68') as string) as Col68,  
    from 
        Kafka_Source
    where
        Condition_3
```